# Remove Server Response Header IIS7

Tags: security, iis-7, header, response

Is there any way to remove "Server" response header from IIS7? There are some articles showing that using HttpModules we can achieve the same thing. This will be helpful if we don't have admin right to server. Also I don't want to write ISAPI filter.

I have admin rights to my server. So I don't want to do the above stuff. So, please help me to do the same.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401219/remove-server-response-header-iis-8-0-8-5#39472251

Answer (score 125):

Add this to your global.asax.cs:

```cs
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
}
```

Comment: I tried the registry option from @Richard above with no luck. I'm using Win 2008 R2 and the registry key was missing so I added a new DWORD key, which may have been incorrect.

This option worked perfectly though. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know why the http module answer is higher than this one, this one is much easier

Comment: This is the simplest method I've found to remove the 'Server' header from IIS7 responses. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. very small change

Comment: For me it is displaying an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I am stuck here

Comment: You might find you get a `NullReferenceException` in Cassini if you rely on `HttpContext.Current`. [This blog post](http://www.bugwriter.me/2010/01/removing-unnecessary-http-header-server.html) shows how to do so whilst avoiding breaking Cassini support, if that is important to you.

Comment: Weirdly, given this worked for me in September, this is no longer working for me. I can only assume one of the recent Windows Updates  messed with it (presumably the one that also added [`net.tcp` and other bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9440744/205245) the other day.

Comment: @PsychoDad this works for ASP.NET requests only, not for static files like .css and .js

Comment: Using IIS 8.0, I'm only seeing the Server header on ASP.NET requests, but not on static files.  When I add Response.Headers.Remove("Server"); I don't get the Server header at all.

Comment: To get rid of the MVC header you can do this
MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the `PreSendRequestHeaders` in a class that implements `IHttpModule` or `Global.asax`. I have witnessed the event freezing the app on the server under stress load. The `BeginRequest` event should work to make response header changes. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChecklistWhatNOTToDoInASPNET.aspx .

Comment: Can put this in EndRequest instead if you prefer, may avoid above freeze risk under load: protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs ev) { Response.Headers.Remove("Server"); }

Comment: As noted in other answers there are problems with this approach (e.g. error requests are not affected). It seems that from IIS10+ there is a way to remove this headers for good with web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222946/1671558

Answer (score 78):

In IIS7 you have to use an HTTP module. Build the following as a class library in VS:

```cs
namespace StrongNamespace.HttpModules
{
  public class CustomHeaderModule : IHttpModule
  { 
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
      context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
    } 

    public void Dispose() { } 

    void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "Box of Bolts");
    }
  }
}
```

Then add the following to your web.config, or you configure it within IIS (if you configure within IIS, the assembly must be in the GAC).

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="CustomHeaderModule"
       type="StrongNamespace.HttpModules.CustomHeaderModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Excellent, I can also tweak this to remove the ETag header across my server farm.

Comment: This causes a runtime error in casini... / ASP.NET Dev server

Comment: Modifying header values requires IIS7 Integrated Mode, however the exception is ignored unless another exception is thrown in the context of the request. Per the title, the question was targeted at IIS7, not casini.

Comment: @UpTheCreek The ASP.Net dev server (Cassini) won't like that code; [this blog post](http://www.bugwriter.me/2010/01/removing-unnecessary-http-header-server.html) has a solution to it, though — you need to check that the `HttpApplication`, the `HttpRequest`, the `HttpContext`, and the `HttpResponse` are not `null`, as well as checking that `HttpRequest.IsLocal` is `false`.

Comment: Weirdly, given this worked for me in September, this is no longer working for me. I can only assume one of the recent Windows Updates  messed with it (presumably the one that also added [`net.tcp` and other bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9440744/205245) the other day.

Comment: As modifying the header in `PreSendRequestHeaders` could [cause issues with HttpCacheModule](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2010/10/18/heap-corruption-in-httpcachemodule-while-you-try-to-remove-http-headers-in-your-custom-http-module.aspx), you should use something like `PostReleaseRequestState` instead.

Comment: The module is not invoked when IIS sends 304 Not Modified header for static files (css / less / images / etc) as this does not reach the ASP.NET pipeline, so in this situation Server: Microsoft IIS/7.5 is still rendered

Comment: This page is a top result for Google search "server "box of bolts"", so don't forget to change it to something unique or simply remove it by `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");`

Comment: Note: if you use it with GAC you should write it with the full qualified name like "StrongNamespace.HttpModules.CustomHeaderModule, StrongNamespace, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31FF3856AF364G35"

Comment: *Warning:* using `HttpContext.Current.Response` instead of `Response` property may cause a NullReferenceException!

Comment: As noted in other answers there are problems with this approach (e.g. error requests are not affected). It seems that from IIS10+ there is a way to remove this headers for good with web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222946/1671558

Answer (score 67):

Scott Mitchell provides in a blog post solutions for [removing unnecessary headers](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506093425/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120209-1.aspx).

As already said here in other answers, for the `Server` header, there is the [http module solution](/a/1201377/1178314), or a [web.config solution for IIS 10+](/a/53222946/1178314), or you can use [URLRewrite instead for blanking it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615970/1178314).

For this `Server` header, the most practical solution for an up-to-date (IIS 10 +) setup is using [`removeServerHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/#attributes) in the web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <security>
    <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
  </security>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

For `X-AspNet-Version` and `X-AspNetMvc-Version`, Scott Mitchell provides a better way than removing them on each response: simply not generating them at all.

Use `enableVersionHeader` for disabling `X-AspNet-Version`, in web.config

```xml
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Use `MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader` in .Net Application_Start event for disabling `X-AspNetMvc-Version`

```cs
MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
```

And finally, remove in IIS configuration the `X-Powered-By` custom header in web.config.

```xml
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

Beware, if you have ARR (Application Request Routing), it will also add its own `X-Powered-By`, which will not be removed by custom headers settings. This one has to be removed through the IIS Manager, Editor configuration on the IIS root (not on a site): go to `system.webServer/proxy` node and set `arrResponseHeader` to `false`. After an `IISReset`, it is taken into account.
(I have found this one [here](https://forums.iis.net/post/2019758.aspx), excepted this post is about old IIS 6.0 way of configuring things.)

Do not forget that solution by application code does not apply by default to header generated on static content (you may activate the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` for changing that, but it causes all requests to run .Net pipeline). It is not an issue for `X-AspNetMvc-Version` since it is not added on static content (at least if static request are not run in .Net pipeline).

Side note: when the aim is to cloak used technology, you should also change standard .Net cookie names (`.ASPXAUTH` if forms auth activated (use `name` attribute on `forms` tag in web.config), `ASP.NET_SessionId` (use `<sessionState cookieName="yourName" />` in web.config under `system.web` tag), `__RequestVerificationToken` (change it by code with `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName`, but unfortunately does not apply to the hidden input this system generates in the html)).

Comment: I added this code   <security>
    <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
  <requestFiltering>
    <denyUrlSequences>
      <add sequence="xmlrpc.php" />
    </denyUrlSequences>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
once I added "requestFiltering" server error appears. If i remove "requestFiltering " it works fine. I want to hide IIS and it's version discloser.  My IIS is 10.0. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Comments are not suitable for answering questions, better ask another question, after having double checked you meet the requirements documented by Microsoft. (My answer links toward this documentation.)

Comment: <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />  -> This gives warning "attribute" is not allowed.

Comment: @AshishShukla, this is not the case in VS2019. Update your configuration schema in your current IDE.

Comment: Thanks, `<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />` works for me. I am using IIS 10. The URL Rewrite rule I had seems to have broken since upgrading to IIS 10.

Comment: The question was for IIS 7 and this doesn't work in IIS 7

Comment: Most of the answer does work with IIS7 and the parts which do not are properly highlighted.

Comment: I'm sorry but posting a solution for IIS 10 in a topic that is specifically about IIS 7 warrants downvoting.

Comment: I still cannot get it. Outdated content is a plague. I intend to go-on completing my answers to keep them up-to-date, in the same way I have done here: mentioning from which version it applies and keeping older solutions mentioned. The sentence right above the IIS 10+ solution for the `Server` header is about them, linking toward other answers addressing this point for IIS < 10.
What would be the alternative? Duping the question for each new version of IIS? It would cause the optimal answers for each reader case to be quite harder to find.

Comment: Is there a way to make an older version of IIS just ignore these IIS 10 only attributes? If I add them into the web.config, the web app won't start using IIS 8 :(

Comment: Not that I know of. If you have to use the same web.config for different IIS versions, you have to use only features supported by the lowest one.

Answer (score 46):

With the URL Rewrite Module Version 2.0 for IIS (UrlRewrite) enabled, in the configuration section `<configuration>` ➡ `<system.webServer>` ➡ `<rewrite>` add the outbound rule:

```xml
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
  </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Note that this only blanks the Server header, it does not remove it.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but to which part should I add this in ?!
I tried adding it inside <system.webServer>

Comment: Thanks! Works in IIS 8.5, this is so easy. I don't have a text editor but you can easily use the GUI. The name should be RESPONSE_Server, not just Server (this is where I failed at first).

Comment: this is good enough if you got a non-ASP.Net application therefor you can't remove server header with mentioned codes

Comment: @vignesh this is some UrlRewrite config subnodes. You have to put them under a `rewrite` node in `system.webServer`. Beware, this will crash your site if UrlRewrite is not installed on the server. And you'd better use the IIS configuration console first to check how it write down those config nodes.

Comment: if 500 Internal Server Error occurs for the configured website it is revealing server info.Can anyone help on this

Comment: You can now get rid of Server response for good. At least from IIS10+ there is a way to remove this headers with web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222946/1671558

Comment: the question was for IIS7 and the rest of the responses did not work in IIS7 as the other people even said they were for IIS10.  this one worked.  good stuff +1

Answer (score 25):

This `web.config` setup works to remove all unnecessary headers from the ASP.NET response (at least starting from IIS 10):

```html
<system.web>
    <!-- Removes version headers from response -->
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <!--Removes X-Powered-By header from response -->
            <clear />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <security>
        <!--Removes Server header from response-->
        <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Please note that this hides all the headers for the "application", as do all the other approaches. If you e.g. reach some default page or an error page generated by the IIS itself or ASP.NET outside your application these rules won't apply. So ideally they should be on the root level in IIS and that sill may leave some error responses to the IIS itself.

P.S. There is a [bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/iis-docs/issues/76) in IIS 10 that makes it sometimes show the server header even with correct config. It should be fixed by now, but IIS/Windows has to be updated.

Comment: <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" /> This gives warning "attribute is not allowed".

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I'm sorry but posting a solution for IIS 10 in a topic that is specifically about IIS 7 warrants downvoting.

Comment: Is there a way to make IIS 7 ignore these IIS 10 only attributes? If I add them to the web.config, the web app will be unable to start with IIS 7 :(

Answer (score 22):

Actually the coded modules and the Global.asax examples shown above only work for valid requests.

For example, add < on the end of your URL and you will get a "Bad request" page which still exposes the server header.  A lot of developers overlook this.

The registry settings shown do not work either.  URLScan is the ONLY way to remove the "server" header (at least in IIS 7.5).

Comment: It's working for me with the coded module (added in web.config) even on an bad request ;)
In global.asax it's not really working (e.g. static files etc.)

Comment: Lets hope you still have request validation switched on.

Comment: does anyone have an alternative to urlscan for IIS 8+?

Comment: There is a working solution at least in IIS10+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222967/1671558

Answer (score 18):

Or add in web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
            <remove name="X-AspNetMvc-Version" />
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            <!-- <remove name="Server" />  this one doesn't work -->
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This method doesn't remove the 'Server' header. The others are removed.

Comment: You can get rid of the X-Powered-By in the Response headers configuration on the server level.

Comment: I don't know if there is a cases where this way removes `X-AspNet-Version` and `X-AspNetMvc-Version` header. What I know is this way does not always work (if it ever works). See @Frederic answer for a more reliable way to remove them.

Comment: There is a way now in IIS10+ to remove the server header: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222946/1671558

Answer (score 13):

Addition to the [URL Rewrite answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615970/1218980), here is the complete XML for `web.config`

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="Company name" />
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

[URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: Does this remove all IIS and ASP versions from hacker

Comment: The above fix is working correctly for the web pages.But for images/icons if 500 Internal Server Error occurred it's showing the Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 instead of the value.Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 11):

To remove the `Server:` header, go to `Global.asax`, find/create the `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` event and add a line as follows (thanks to [BK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338448/590558) and [this blog](http://www.bugwriter.me/2010/01/removing-unnecessary-http-header-server.html) this will also not fail on the Cassini / local dev):

```cs
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove the "Server" HTTP Header from response
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    if (null != app && null != app.Request && !app.Request.IsLocal &&
        null != app.Context && null != app.Context.Response)
    {
        NameValueCollection headers = app.Context.Response.Headers;
        if (null != headers)
        {
            headers.Remove("Server");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a complete solution to remove all related headers on Azure/IIS7 and also works with Cassini, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without), which shows the best way to disable these headers without using HttpModules or URLScan.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to remove the header you can use a shortened version of lukiffer's answer:

```cs
using System.Web;

namespace Site
{
    public sealed class HideServerHeaderModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose() { }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders +=
            (sender, e) => HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `Web.config`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="CustomHeaderModule" type="Site.HideServerHeaderModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is most appropriate because resources like css/js will not have the Server header, it ports from server to server without configuration and the Server response header won't just be empty, it will not be sent.

Comment: I have seen comments that runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" will slow down your app and is not recommended. Instead one could use urlrewrite module outboundRules to clear the server value also for static files. http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableServerHeader` registry entry to a `REG_DWORD` of `1`.

Comment: Ran into an odd situation with our server farm where this registry setting seems to be the only change that works across all of the OS's (W2K8, W2K3) we're using, for both IIS6 and IIS7.

Comment: Frustratingly, this isn't making any difference for me, even after rebooting the virtual machine. We're running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, "Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)". Similarly, my `OnPreSendRequestHeaders` event handler (see above) is never firing, for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately the registry key doesn't seem to work on IIS 7.5

Answer (score 4):

[UrlScan](http://www.iis.net/extensions/UrlScan)  can also remove the server header by using `AlternateServerName=` under `[options]`.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on [eddiegroves' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252865), depending on the version of URLScan, you may instead prefer `RemoveServerHeader=1` under `[options]`.

I'm not sure in which version of URLScan this option was added, but it has been available in version 2.5 and later.

Answer (score 2):

I found an article that explains why we need to do both Registry edit and use a tool such as UrlScan to set this up in IIS properly. I followed it on our servers and it works: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers.aspx. If you only use UrlScan but don't do the registry change, during the time you are stopping World Wide Publishing Service, your server will return server http response from the HTTP.sys file. Also, here are common pitfals of using UrlScan tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648552.aspx#ht_urlscan_008

Comment: Please post your code on Stack Overflow. Links can change and break, so posting code is much more helpful

Answer (score 2):

In IIS 10, we use a similar solution to Drew's approach, i.e.:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Common.Web.Modules.Http
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets custom headers in all requests (e.g. "Server" header) or simply remove some.
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomHeaderModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
        }

        public void Dispose() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler that implements the desired behavior for the PreSendRequestHeaders event,
        /// that occurs just before ASP.NET sends HTTP headers to the client.
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "MyServer");
        }
    }
}
```

And obviously add a reference to that dll in your project(s) and also the module in the config(s) you want:

```html
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--Use http module to remove/customize IIS "Server" header-->
      <add name="CustomHeaderModule" type="Common.Web.Modules.Http.CustomHeaderModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

IMPORTANT NOTE1: This solution needs an application pool set as integrated;

IMPORTANT NOTE2: All responses within the web app will be affected by this (css and js included);

Answer (score 1):

I had researched this and the URLRewrite method works well.  Can't seem to find the change scripted anywhere well.  I wrote this compatible with PowerShell v2 and above and tested it on IIS 7.5.

```
# Add Allowed Server Variable
    Add-WebConfiguration /system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables -atIndex 0 -value @{name="RESPONSE_SERVER"}
# Rule Name
    $ruleName = "Remove Server Response Header"
# Add outbound IIS Rewrite Rule
    Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "iis:\" -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/outboundrules" -name "." -value @{name=$ruleName; stopProcessing='False'}
#Set Properties of newly created outbound rule 
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/rule[@name='$ruleName']/match" -name "serverVariable" -value "RESPONSE_SERVER"
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/rule[@name='$ruleName']/match" -name "pattern" -value ".*"
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/rule[@name='$ruleName']/action" -name "type" -value "Rewrite"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code in Global.asax.cs file

```
    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed above in combination worked for me with following changes. Here I am posting my scenario and solution.

For me I wanted to remove the following headers:

- Server
- X-Powered-By
- X-AspNet-Version
- X-AspNetMvc-Version

**I added these to my global.asax:**

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
    }
</script>
```

The above event was not getting triggered, so for that I added following to web.config then it worked.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

and for removing version header I also added following to web.config:

```
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

**Changes in web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the stuff here and on several other similar stack overflow threads.

I got hung up for a bit because I forgot to clear my browser cache after making config changes.  If you don't do that and the file is in your local cache, it will serve it back to you with the original headers (duh).

I got it mostly working by *removing* the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

This removed the extraneous headers from **most** of the static files but I still was getting the "Server" header on some static files in my WebAPI project in swagger.

I finally found and applied this solution and now **all** of the unwanted headers are gone:

https://www.dionach.com/en-au/blog/easily-remove-unwanted-http-headers-in-iis-7-0-to-8-5/

which discusses his code that is here:

https://github.com/Dionach/StripHeaders/releases/tag/v1.0.5

This is a Native-Code module.  It is able to **remove** the Server header, not just blank out the value.  By default it removes:

- Server
- X-Powered-By
- X-Aspnet-Version
- Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0  -- which would be returned if "the request fails to be passed to IIS"

Answer (score -1):

IIS 7.5 and possibly newer versions have the header text stored in `iiscore.dll`

Using a hex editor, find the string and the word "Server" `53 65 72 76 65 72` after it and replace those with null bytes. In IIS 7.5 it looks like this:

```
4D 69 63 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2D 49 49 53 2F 37 2E 35 00 00 00 53 65 72 76 65 72
```

Unlike some other methods this does not result in a performance penalty. The header is also removed from all requests, even internal errors.

Comment: Yikes. Please let this be a joke.