# Return CSV response without headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, response

I am writing an ASP.NET application that generates CSV string and returns it using response.write. However, along with the CSV string, the output comes with other information I would like to get rid of (e.g. ASP.NET version, time-stamp) etc. How can I just get the CSV string and nothing else?

Comment: Code speaks louder than words - can you post your code, a sample of the output and point out what is the issue with the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IIS7 with integrated pipeline mode you should be able to access Headers:

```
this.Response.Headers.Add() / Remove() etc.
this.Response.ClearHeaders();
this.Response.AddHeader("key", "value");
```

You're best bet might be to create an HttpModule and return your CSV from it.  See answer here [`HttpApplication.PreSendRequestHeaders`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7)