# what are these IIS binding and what is their purpose?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I am administoring a very old IIS system that has been upgraded from 5.0, to 6.0 and now 7.0.

The Default Web Site has some bindings associated with it with the following:

```
Type:  http, Port: 80, IPAddress: *, Binding Info:
Type: net.tcp, Port: Empty, IPAddress: Empty, Binding Info: 808:*
Type: net.pipe, Port: Empty, IPAddress: Empty, Binding Info: *
Type: net.msmq, Port: Empty, IPAddress: Empty, Binding Info: localhost
Type: msmq.formatname, Port: Empty, IPAddress: Empty, Binding Info: localhost
```

What are the net.tcp, net.pip, net.msmq, and msmq.formtname?  What are they used for and why are the being bound in the IIS default site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you enable WCF, then the extra bindings are added. If you don't use WCF at all, feel free to remove them.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail, please? We use WCF to connect to third-party web services, but I would assume that (because we're not _hosting_ any web services) we don't need these protocols activated. Would I be right?

Comment: If your application on this server only consumes web services on other machines, and does not publish web services on this server, then you can safely remove other bindings.