# Remove HTTP Header "Server". in IIS 6

Tags: http-headers, iis-6

I am using VS 2008 with IIS6. I want to remove the server tag from the Http Header "Server".
I used the following code in my Global.asax.

```
void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object src, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

It shows the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". 
How can I solve this

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that worked for me (for IIS6):

1. Download and install [UrlScan 2.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12719) on the webserver
2. Open the UrlScan configuration file (%windir%\system32\inetsrv\urlscan\urlscan.ini)
3. Locate the RemoveServerHeader line and set the value to 1 (should read RemoveServerHeader=1)
4. Reset IIS and test if header is gone

Just for the record... you can achieve this by code with a custom HttpModule if you upgrade to IIS 7 (integrated pipeline mode).

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12804722/2074016. It has additional error handling that may fix your error:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove the "Server" HTTP Header from response
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    if (null != app && null != app.Request && !app.Request.IsLocal &&
        null != app.Context && null != app.Context.Response)
    {
        NameValueCollection headers = app.Context.Response.Headers;
        if (null != headers)
        {
            headers.Remove("Server");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires IIS Pipeline mode which is not available in IIS6 as the OP question states.