# how to remove response headers for image css and js requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I have deployed a web application

I wanted to remove the server information and i was able to achieve it in handlers by adding these lines in `global.asax` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12803974/848841)

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (application != null && application.Context != null)
            {
                application.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            }

        }
```

Now this removes headers for XHR requests, but still i am able to find server information in the image request's response headers!! How to remove them?

Answer (score 3):

I found another similar question here. The leading answer was to add this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>     
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">     
   </modules>     
</system.webServer>
```

Take a look at all the answers here: [Removing Server header from static content in IIS 7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305195/removing-server-header-from-static-content-in-iis-7-8)

Comment: should i add that under system.web