# How to remove information about IIS from Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, response-headers

I want to remove information about IIS version from Response Headers. In Global.asax is Application_PreSendRequestContent event or I can implement IHttpModule and do it in:

```
void context_PreSendRequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
...
```

or

```
static void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // remove the "Server" Http Header
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
```

But I got error: `{"This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."}` when I want to read context.Response.Headers property. I have Windows XP and VS 2008.

Thanks

Comment: See this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7

Comment: If I good understand I have to user HTTP rewrite module. Rest of these methods I was trying and without result