# OWIN Change Response Server Identity?

Tags: http-headers, owin, katana

I have a simple OWIN Middleware at the end of a chain, and I am setting the Server header value like this:

```
myiowincontext.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
myiowincontext.Response.Headers.Set("Server" ,"owin");
return myiowincontext.Response.WriteAsync( "hello world" );
```

But that appears to only change the header from

```
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

to

```
Server: owin Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`
```

What is the proper way to set the Server header value to something custom, without including the "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0" part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This header is inserted by HTTP.SYS on the outgoing responses. Since HTTP.SYS sees you already have a Server header on your response, it simply appends it. To remove the default server header inserted by HTTP.SYS I see some registry key suggestions [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1171860.aspx). But it did not work for me though some people have told it works for them. Try your luck. [This](http://www.iis-answers.com/microsoft/IIS/31870952/removing-server-header-doesnt-work.aspx) post suggests that removing this key does not improve the security in any way - so the solution to remove the key was removed. Another suggestion that many posts suggest is using [UrlScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7).