# Remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin Response Header

Tags: security, iis-7, header, cors

I want to remove **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`** vulnerability from  Response Header.

I added the following line of codes into web.config which I found from this [website](https://www.netsparker.com/web-vulnerability-scanner/vulnerability-security-checks-index/misconfigured-access-control-allow-origin-header/).

I also apply some of the method that given in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7).

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="domain" />
</customHeaders>
```

But it does not remove **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`** instead of adding **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain`** in the Response Header.

[image]

I have no idea how to remove this response header, as when I google for the solution. Most of the posts were trying to enable this header.

Please let me know if need more information.

Thanks in advance.

**P/S: The website is build on PHP and running on IIS 7.**

Answer (score 0):

use a `<remove>` tag.

```
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
```

If you want to add a more restrictive Access-Control-Allow-Origin, you can then put it after the `<remove>`.