# Server Header Information Showing up in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am facing an issue where server header information is showing up in IIS. I know by using URL rewrite module and creating outbound rule will resolve the issue. Problem here is when i am checking individual severs i am seeing server header information as Server:-Microsoft-IIS/7.5. and when i am checking LB URL i am seeing server:- IA Web server. not sure from where this text is coming up.I checked the web.config file but the entry for witting own server information is not present in an tag. Also one more information i have akamai implemented after the web servers. Could some one help in this context.

Answer (score 0):

This is added by IIS Server. Adding outbound URL-Rewrite rule is the best way to go as adding a custom HTTPModule to remove headers or through global.asax.cs as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7) won't work for static files.

See detailed blog here - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/