# ** Burn Strip ** tool remove ( Server : Microsoft-IIS/10.0 ) asp.net with 404 azure error

Tags: asp.net

I have IIS 10.0 installed on my Windows server .net framework (4.0).

I am trying to remove the Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 header from my responses.

`Code Implemented into the web.config`
[image: Code Implemented into the web.config]

`When I am trying to test this by **Burp Suite**:`

[image: Before Injecting Host into Response Header]

[image: After Injecting Host into Response Header]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Server Response Header IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7)

Comment: Problem we are facing when throw Microsoft Azure Web App - Error 404