# Prevent Azure Application Gateway v1 redirect to Listener from returning server header

Tags: azure-application-gateway

When doing an http to https redirection in Application Gateway v1 by using redirection in a rule to another listener, the redirect response to the browser travels with the Server header set.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I'm not returning that header from the application and this is exposing that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below workaround:

Also to remove all unnecessary headers from the ASP.NET response ,try to modify `web.config` .

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Removes version headers from response -->
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <!--Removes following header from response -->
<remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
            <remove name="X-AspNetMvc-Version" />
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <security>
        <!--Removes Server header from response-->
        <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

or

Try to use the application gateway to remove these headers: [delete-unwanted-header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#delete-unwanted-headers) (used in v2 )

[image]

**References:**

1. [Removing standard server headers on Windows Azure Web Sites | Azure Blog and Updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)
2. [security - Remove Server Response Header IIS7 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7/62796428#62796428)
3. [Rewrite HTTP headers with Azure Application Gateway | Azure Blog and Updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/rewrite-http-headers-with-azure-application-gateway/)

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. The first option wouldn't work though, right? I think that's what's failing right now. Because the redirect at the gateway level doesn't even reach the app, so the web config never comes into play.

Comment: Also seems the second option doesn't work when app gateway is configured for redirection :( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#limitations